# How to configure route parameter on Angular application root URL

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

Seems simple enough... my app.module looks like this:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent },
  { path: ':config', component: AppComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and the app.component code looks like this:

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  config: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.config = this.route.snapshot.params['config'];
  }
```

I want to be able to do something like hit http://localhost:4200/english and have the config property set to 'english'... but this.route.snapshot.params['config'] is undefined every time.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try `this.route.params.subscribe(params => { this.config =params['config']})`

Answer (score 1):

There's actually nothin wrong of how you extract the params on your ngOnInit() but there's something wrong of how you missed to place your router-outlet (my assumption).

**AppComponent**

> AppComponent is the root (router-outlet) that will handle all of your child routes.
>
> If you are fetching your route parameter and your AppComponent's Template is just a Plain HTML without the `<router-outlet>` then your `this.route.snapshot.params['config'];` will become **undefined**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `I am AppComponent`        // Plain Template without <router-outlet>
})
export class AppComponent {...}
```

> But if you will place the `<router-outlet>` on your AppComponent's Template, then your `this.route.snapshot.params['config'];` will have a value, if the passed config parameter is *'/english'* then its snapshot param value is **'english'**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
     <h1>{{ config }}</h1>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>     // Add router-outlet
  `        
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    config: string;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.config = this.route.snapshot.params['config'];    // 'english' if the url has a supplied param of /english 
    }

}
```

---

Had created [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-root-param) for your reference in regards to your concern

**Demo Output**

[image: Demo]

Comment: Many thanks for that! I noticed one subtlety in my own code... I use a templateURL rather than a template, and in the corresponding template html file, it seems to matter where you put the router outlet. If I put the router outlet at the top, things work as expected. If I put it after the reference to the variable it should be setting ('config', in this case), it doesn't work. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @IvanPelly, your welcome. If my answer helps you with your concern. Mind if you'll mark it as an accepted answer? That would be a great help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @KShewengger - thanks again! I played with the Stackblitz demo a little more, and, unless I'm misunderstanding it, I'm no longer 100% convinced that it's correct. In the demo, I did the following: 1) remove all the markup from app.component.html (not needed), 2) type 'hello' on the line before <router-outlet> in app.component.ts 3) append '/test' to the URL in the righthand pane. When the test page loads, 'Hello' is repeated twice. I bet it's got something to do with the component being its own router outlet, but I haven't quite figured out what would make it work yet.

Comment: hello when i use templateUrl, i am getting duplicate response.. were you able to solve it

Comment: Hi, to avoid having duplicate response on the custom template you have assigned inside the AppComponent along with router-outlet, we must separate it on another component or url since the duplicate is triggered since we have made the "AppComponent" as our main component which we have configured to be put inside the "bootstrap" config in our AppModule NgModule "bootstrap: [AppComponent ]". Unlike other components that are not bootstrapped, it will not duplicate your response.

Comment: am very curious to see your demo. when i pass "english" in the url the hello component is called. How it its being called ? i want to call specific component on the same. I am getting blank page. please help

Comment: Hi @Santosh sorry for the late reply. I am very sorry for the confusion. The HelloComponent is another example if you want to access the params inside the SubComponent, so you can update our Angular routing inside the AppModule and Change the AppComponent to HelloComponent, you can then see the reflected result. The current example also supports the console for the route param inside the AppComponent. So whichever you like or suits you best, you can use either way :) 

Hope this help :)

Comment: This solution will render AppComponent twice, just change the html of your stackblitz to `<ng-container *ngIf="!!config; else noConfig">
 <h1>{{ config }}</h1>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noConfig>
 No Config
</ng-template>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and try